# In Windows 11, is there a way to show desktop by right-clicking the taskbar?

Tags: windows-11, taskbar, desktop

On Windows 10, I was really accustomed to showing desktop by right-clicking the taskbar and selecting "Show desktop". That was easier to me than clicking on the bottom-right corner. Now I switched to Windows 11 and this possibility seems to be lost.

I searched on Google but, as every other possible research, it only shows me again and again the same results, i.e. how to show desktop by clicking on the bottom-right corner.

Is it possible to restore this functionality?

Comment: Bottom right corner has been the (more or less) default way of getting to the Desktop for a long time. Windows 11 has made this now the way to get to desktop. It is easier now because the mouse stops there.

Comment: If you want to try a shortcut key for that, you can use windows key + d

Comment: @John The mouse stops at the bottom of the screen too, which seems easier to me than going to the bottom *and* right. Especially if you have the desktop extended over more than one monitor.

Comment: Try a third-party tool, such as https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/ or alternatives, https://alternativeto.net/software/classic-start/. They have the advantage of keeping the same look and feel even when MS updates the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of...   You can right click the Start button and select "Desktop"

[image: right click on Start button]

Answer (score 0):

There's always <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to minimize everything that's open

Comment: doesnt answer the question being asked.  also, windows+d is better, as you can minimize and maximize with it

Comment: Fair. And thanks, Win+D not only allows maximizing too, but is much easier to do with one hand.